# any computational analytic number theory book?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, book-recommendation

All:

Can anyone recommend an introduction computational analytic number theory book ?
I am mainly interested in using computer software to verify and confirm analytic number theorem, things related: Dirichelt Series, trigonometric sums, Riemann Zeta, etc.

I know there are books on computational algebraic number theory, just wonder if there is similar books for analytic number theory.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Borwein book?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any book that's exactly what you want, but you might have a look at Peter Borwein's book, Computational Excursions in Analysis and Number Theory.